Radiate a pattern of hexagons around a circle?
I am trying to create a pattern of hexagons that radiate outward from a circle (depiction below only shows a portion, but actual execution needs to be around the entire circle).
I don't know if the Array modifier will do that, since it needs to have the constant step, and would turn into a spiral. Also, the pattern needs to have some distortion to squeeze elements as they are moving towards the circle.
Does anyone know a way to do this either procedurally or how to make the Array function work?

